# df.to_csv saving 03 as 3 in csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

sample file:

```
03|02|2|02|F|3|47|P| |AG|AFL|24|20201016|          1 |West      |CH|India      - LA     |CNDO
```

code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("GM3.txt",sep="|",dtype=object)
df1.to_csv('file_validation.csv',index=None)
```

output in csv:

```
3   2   2   2   F   3   47  P       AG  AFL 24  20201016    1   West        CH  India      - LA         CNDO    302
```

when I am trying to print df1.to_csv() it is giving me below output:
0                03          02               2                   CH  India      - LA                      CNDO

I want csv to be stored as string format i.e. 03,02 instead of integer.

Comment: Have you tried removing `dtype=object`? Also, to_csv defaults to write commas, so how are you viewing the data?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have tried without mentioning dtype and dtype=str also still getting same result. as i pasted the output from csv it is not showing coma separated

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("GM3.txt",sep="|",dtype=object)
df1.to_csv('file_validation.csv',index=None)
```

produces

[image: screenshot of code]